Prove that $n^{-1} f(nx) \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ almost everywhere if i) $f \in L^1(\mathbb R)$ and ii) $f$ is Lebesgue integrable
Prove that $n^{-1} f(nx) \rightarrow 0$ almost everywhere as $n \rightarrow \infty$ in two cases:

$f \in L^1(\mathbb R)$,
$f$ is Lebesgue integrable on $\mathbb R$.

I understand how this is proven in the first case. We can let $f_n = n^{-1}f(nx)$ and consider the sequence $(\sum_{n=1}^N \int |f_n|)_{N \geq 1}$. We can then use the fact that $f \in L^1(\mathbb R)$ to confirm that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int |f_n| < \infty$. Then by Monotone Convergence Theorem, we deduce that $\int \sum_{n=1}^\infty |f_n| < \infty$. And so, ultimately we can deduce that $f_n \rightarrow 0$ almost everywhere, otherwise the integral would diverge.
My issue is with the second case. Does a similar strategy to the first case work? If so, how would we ensure that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int |f_n| < \infty$ if $f$ is not necessarily a function from $L^1(\mathbb R)$?
Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

For most people the assertion "$f$ is Lebesgue integrable" would be equivalent to "$f$ belongs in $L^1$", thus you might have a different definition for either of these concepts that you might want to write down.

@BrunoB Lebesgue integrability was defined to be that there exists a sequence of functions $f_n$ such that each $f_n = \sum_i a_i \chi_{A_i}$ takes on only countably many values $a_1, a_2, \dots$ and $\chi_{A_i}$ is the indicator variable for set $A_i$ where the $A_i$'s partition the reals. Furthermore $f_n$ themselves are integrable in the sense that $\sum_i |a_i| m(A_i) < \infty$ where $m(\cdot)$ denotes measure. And lastly that $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$. Then $f$ is integrable and its integral is the limit of the integral of these f_n's. Is this synonymous with being in $L^1$?

@Aester Yes, they are equivalent.

@stoic-santiago How do we deduce they are equivalent? We need to somehow show that $\lim_n \int |f_n| = \int |f| < \infty$? I can see that by definition, $\int |f_n| < \infty$ for every $n$, but how do we know it remains true when we take the limit?
